# Rails 3.1 interdependent select dropdown lists

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html-select

My database structure:

```
Countries(id,title,prefix)  
Towns(id,country_id,title)
Street(id,town_id,title)
```

I need to create interdependent select dropdown list: when i select Country, ajax loading towns from this country into select tag, and when i select Street, ajax loading street by selected town_id into street select tag.
I want to ask whether there is a Rails way to generate this list. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found some tutorial to make what you want :

- [dependant dropdowns menus](http://programmers-blog.com/2009/11/12/dependant-dropdowns-select-menus-using-rails)
- [cascading menu](http://www.falsepositives.com/index.php/2010/05/28/building-a-casscading-drop-down-selection-list-for-ruby-on-rails-with-jquery-ajax/)